# Can't delete element from vector, attempting to reference deleted function

Tags: c++, sfml, 2d-games

I am making my "version" of Space Invaders in C++ using SFML library but I have a problem when I try to delete an invader.
I have this error in my code:

`Enemy &Enemy::operator =(const Enemy &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

I tried to check other solutions that were recommended in this forum but I either didn't understand them or it was a different case.

EnemyControler.cpp

```
EnemyControler::EnemyControler()
{
    Enemy::Type types[] = {
        Enemy::Type::Squid, Enemy::Type::Crab, Enemy::Type::Crab,
        Enemy::Type::Octopus, Enemy::Type::Octopus
    };


    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) { // Add enemies to the vector
        for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++){
            float enemyX = x * 40 + (gapBetweenEnemies * x * 3) + Enemy::enemyWidth; // Make horizontal gap between them
            float enemyY = y * 40 + (gapBetweenEnemies * y) + Enemy::enemyHeight; // Make vertical gap between them
            enemies.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f{ enemyX, enemyY }, types[y]); // Add them to the vector
        }
    }
}
void EnemyControler::destroyEnemy()
{
    for (auto iterator = begin(enemies); iterator != end(enemies);) {
        auto& enemy = *iterator;
        if (enemy.isAlive()) {
            iterator++;
        }
        else {
            iterator = enemies.erase(iterator);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is in destroyEnemy function. Specifically in `iterator = enemies.erase(iterator);`

EnemyControler.h

```
class EnemyControler
{
public:
    EnemyControler();

    void destroyEnemy();
private:
    const int gapBetweenEnemies = 10;

    std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
Enemy::Enemy(sf::Vector2f startingPosition, Type type) : 
Collidable(enemyWidth, enemyHeight), newPosition(startingPosition), enemyType(type), startingPosition(startingPosition)
{
}
```

Enemy.h

```
class Enemy : public Collidable
{
public:
    enum class Type // enum for different looking enemies
    {
        Crab, Octopus, Squid
    };
    Enemy(sf::Vector2f startingPosition, Type type);

    constexpr static float enemyWidth = 30.0f;
    constexpr static float enemyHeight = 30.0f;

private:
    sf::Vector2f newPosition;
    Type enemyType;

    const sf::Vector2f startingPosition;
};
```

Collidable.cpp

```
Collidable::Collidable(float width, float height) :
 spriteSize(width, height)
{
}
```

Collidable.h

```
class Collidable
{
public:
    Collidable(float width, float height);
private:
    sf::Vector2f spriteSize;
};
```

If there isn't an easy way of fixing this problem or this problem could be fixed only by rewriting all code maybe you could suggest another way of deleting invader from the vector.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class has a `const` member variable, then the copy assignment operator for that class `operator=` is default-deleted by the compiler.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment :

> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>   - T has a non-static data member of non-class type (or array thereof) that is const;

This is because the compiler can't guess what it means to copy assign object `A` into object `B`, if objects of their class contain a `const` member variable. Should the compiler just ignore that particular member variable? Should the compiler guess that you mean it to be `const`, except when copy assigning, then it's okay just this once - I'll look the other way? The compiler has no idea what you would prefer, so it just deletes it.

One option is to explicitly define a copy assignment operator for your class.

However, `startingPosition` is already declared private, so there's little chance of anything outside of the class inadvertently changing it. I recommend just removing the `const` specifier.

### Why does the copy assignment operator matter? I'm trying to delete things, not copy assign them

When an element is erased from a `vector`, all elements in the `vector` "above" the erased element need to be moved down to fill the gap. This happens via the copy assignment operator.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase :

> Complexity
>   Linear: the number of calls to the destructor of T is the same as the number of elements erased, the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Sadly deleting const or adding static doesn't help. I edited answer and added Enemy class that could be problem as there are constexpr but with static, So I have no idea.

Comment: I misread your `EnemyControler` class as your `Enemy` class. The issue is with `const sf::Vector2f startingPosition;` in your `Enemy` class.

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you understand why, though? That will help your understanding of future problems of this type.

Comment: I think I understand. But I am not quite sure what static does.

Comment: Declaring non-static member variables as const is usually a mistake, because of issues like this.

Comment: `static` on a member variables encapsulates the member variable in the namespace of the class (as all member variables of that class are encapsulated in its namespace), without actually filling the data of *objects* of that class with that variable. It means all instances of the class share that member variable. Changing it in object of the class changes it for all other objects of the class. It's for when you want them to share some trait or object.

Comment: Okay, then will it better to use const static and not only const?

Comment: To be clear: my advice is to *remove `const`* from `startingPosition`, not to *add `static`* to `startingPosition`.

Comment: That depends. Do you want all enemies to have the same starting position?

Comment: Yeah, I deleted const and didn't add static. And thank you! Now I know when or at least some cases when to add static. And answer to your question, no I want them to be different.